# Issue with passing Hudson variable as an JMeter command line argument

Tags: jmeter

When I tried passing the hudson variable(WORKSPACE) as a Jmeter command line arguments like `-Jworkspace=${WORKSPACE}`, Jmeter script prints the value as it is. I see output as `${WORKSPACE}`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This is on a linux commandline?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use a OS environment variable as a parameter to a java process is:

```
-Denv_var=%MY_ENV_VAR% (Windows)
-Denv_var=$MY_ENV_VAR (Linux)
```

In your case, assuming you're on linux,

```
-Jworkspace=$WORKSPACE
```

This would only work, if `WORKSPACE` is already a defined environment variable. Check by running `echo $WORKSPACE` on the linux commandline.

You can also access OS environment variables inside JMeter (or any java process really) as `System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR");`